# Logic to check if an object property exists in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a JSON array of objects (items.[{},{},{}]) which I'm mapping as 'item', and am then rendering a JSX image from an URL stored in the property *item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail*. In most cases, 'thumbnail' exists, but sometimes it doesn't (if there's no image), so first I want to check if it exists, and only try to render the image if it does.

When I try to test for undefined (*if (item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail !== undefined)*), I get the error **(TypeError): Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined** (well yeah, that's why I'm doing the test!)

So I tried using 'in', but now my code just does nothing at all, no error but no render either... any tips?

```
this.state.jsonArray.map(item => {
  if ('thumbnail' in item) {
    return <img src={item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail} />
  }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 2):

`(TypeError): Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined` means that on *some* item you are mapping that `item.volumeInfo.imageLinks` is undefined.

> So I tried using 'in', but now my code just does nothing at all, no
> error but no render either...

This is because the `thumbnail` property would be in the `item.volumeInfo.imageLinks` object, not the root `item` object, so this condition is always false and nothing is returned from the map callback.

I would filter first by items that have the thumbnail property, then map. Don't forget to include a React key (anything but the array index will work so long as it's unique among data) so if/when the mapped state updates that rerendering will work.

```
this.state.jsonArray
  .filter(item => item.volumeInfo?.imageLinks?.thumbnail)
  .map(item => (
    <img key={item.id} src={item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail} />
  ))
```

If you are unable to use Optional Chaining then use the conventional null checks.

```
this.state.jsonArray
  .filter(item => {
    return item.volumeInfo &&
      item.volumeInfo.imageLinks &&
      item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
  })
  .map(item => (
    <img key={item.id} src={item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail} />
  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Optional chaining operator** (?.)

```
   this.state.jsonArray.map(item => {
   if (item?.volumeInfo?.imageLinks?.thumbnail) {
    return <img src={item?.volumeInfo?.imageLinks?.thumbnail} />
   }
})
```

The optional chaining will return **undefined** if any property of the item is undefined.